# how render canvas on imageView to show circle moving faster (not jumping)

Tags: android, canvas, imageview, draw, geometry

I have balls class extends ImageView
and on this i have Circle Ball going from left side to right side and in any time speed of Moving increased <

```
     private void render() {
         while (true) {
             Thread.sleep(30);          
             if(x > getwidth()){ 
                 Step++ && x = 0;
             }
             x += step
         }
    }

  private void update() {
         while (true) {
             Thread.sleep(60);          
            Postinvalidate();
         }
    }
```

any thing is Good but when step equals 20 and more < the ball do not movie Rightly and we see it jumping <

I testing the Step = 5 and Thread.sleep(value--) < but did not work Rightly
how can I Move the ball faster and render of onDraw was Rightly

TNX ALL < @};-